# Вопрос по ошибкам в eslint

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, eslint

Подскажите, что и где нужно прописать чтоб игнорировать эти ошибки, мне нужно именно их проигнорировать, так как они осознанно не используются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Читаем [на этой странице](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) правило "неиспользуемых переменных", в особенности как прописать подчеркивание `"...IgnorePattern": "^_"`. Там же можно найти и [все остальное](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-empty)

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите это в начале файла где есть ошибка

```
/*global some_unused_var*/
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Vitalii Bolkot Parsing error: Missing semicolon.

> 1 | global some_unused_var
    |       ^
  2 |
  3 | import firebase from 'firebase';
  4 |eslint
Объявления "module" можно использовать только в файлах TypeScript.ts(8006)

Comment: @salco202020 /* eslint-disable-next-line */ сверху линии где ошибка